# How to do date validation with moment library in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a textbox: `txtDepartureDate` where a user can select the departure date. If the selected date is before today, then I was to show an error message. I have tried using the `moment` library in Javascript to achieve this and also used the `oninput()` event handler. I am trying to subtract today's date with the departure date to get the total number of days and if this is less than or equal to zero, then `lblError` should display the error message. The validation part is not working for me.

`Textbox:`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDepartureDate" runat="server" ForeColor="Gray" onfocus="txtOnFocusDeparture(this)" onblur="txtOnBlurDeparture(this)" oninput="oninputDeparture()" AutoPostBack="True">DEPARTURE DATE</asp:TextBox>
```

`Script:`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    function oninputDeparture() {
                        var inputDate = moment(document.getElementById('txtDepartureDate').value, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
                        var todayDate = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
                        var lblError = document.getElementById('lblError');
                        var daysDiff = todayDate.diff(inputDate, 'days');
                        if (daysDiff <= 0) {
                            lblError.innerText = "Departure Day should be after today";
                        }
                        else {
                            lblError.innerText = "";
                        }

                    }

                </script>
```

Comment: Did you find the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is done:

```
var inputDate = moment([1990, 0, 01]);
var todayDate = moment().toDate();
inputDate.diff(todayDate, 'days')
```

You have to get entered input date in the above format.